# how to tell if a book will be a bestseller?

Tags: novel, publishing, self-publishing, book

I wrote a novel and it is Science fiction based novel.
Almost every close friend of mine read the novel and none of them gave a negative response.
What are the possibilities that I need to assume, which can make my book bestselling.

Comment: Related: [What makes a best seller - writing or setting?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/18252/33442)

Comment: If there was a secret ingredient to figuring that out, there would be far fewer books published that don't sell.

Comment: The odds of any individual book becoming a bestseller (particularly a debut that hasn't gotten further than close friends, yet) are very, very slim. "Bestseller" status relies on writing a fantastic book, finding a publisher willing to put a lot of resources behind it, and a LOT of luck -- if you're looking for certainty in advance, the easy answer is "assume probably not."

Comment: Ask any publishing professional and they will tell you that no one knows. If they did, they would not publish anything else.

Comment: @MarkBaker: Even if they knew from the start which books will become a bestseller, they'd still publish other books as well. Because by the very nature of the term "bestseller" there can only be very few of them, and the publishers would remove a large part of their profits if they only sold bestsellers. What would not happen, though, is that they reject a book that later becomes a bestseller published by someone else.

Comment: @celtschk No, they would not remove most of their profit if they only sold bestsellers, because it is on the bestsellers that they make their profits. Betsy Lerner, in _The Forest for the Trees_ (excellent book!) tells of a management consulting firm who did a study for a major publisher and recommended that they would do much better just publishing the bestsellers. We know, they said, but we don't know which ones they are.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of factors collide to make a book a bestseller. It's not just the writing - there's also how original the concept is, and how much it speaks to the audience, the right place, the right time, and probably more. The same book might not have sold as well had it been published a few years earlier or a few years later. Or it might have sold just as well.

**Having a bestseller is a surprise**. Don't plan for it. Don't expect it. It is a rare thing. If it happens, enjoy the ride while it lasts.

The only exception is famous authors who have already written multiple bestsellers: they can reasonably expect their name alone to sell many books. Although, even a famous author's book can flop. It's just that after you've written several bestsellers, your financial future doesn't depend so very heavily on the next book: it will sell enough even if it isn't a bestseller, and there are the royalties for the other books, and you'll be already writing the next one by the time this one is published.

A final note: you say your *close friends* read your novel. Have you considered the possibility they don't want to give you harsh criticism? Or their perception of your novel is coloured by their friendship with you? Or, being your friends, they like the same thing you do, which might not be the same things a larger chunk of the public would like? Trust your friends' criticism. Be wary in accepting their praise.